# Question on close policy for answered questions

Tags: discussion

Question in relation to "Close" policy and discussion in comments to this post : [Old school Hip Hop song, circa 1999, in background of personal video](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/old-school-hip-hop-song-circa-1999-in-background-of-personal-video).

Although the original video link is dead, the question has an accepted answer, with detail about the song and its lyrics.  There is also a comment to the question which quotes fragments of the lyrics, so no shortage of information there.

Should a question with a detailed accepted answer ever be closed ?

Comment: Related: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/324/3955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you guys talking about **good** answers or **correct** answers...?

To me, a broken-link-only question that has a correct but bad (in SE standards) answer can be **closed and deleted**.

When it comes to ID questions, what I would consider to be a bad however correct answer is an answer that has either been accepted or comment confirmed by OP to be correct.

But is:

- Artist name or title only
- Link only
- No "google potential", no reminder of OP details that match

Comment: @Bebs, your answer is a useful guide.  The site policy on closure should maybe include some/all of that.  I think the question of "Can a good answer save a bad question?" is something that is best decided case by case.

Answer (score 3):

*Full disclosure*: I am the user who raised the flag on the question for closure after noticing that the link to the song is dead.

---

> . . .the question has an accepted answer, with detail about the song and its lyrics. There is also a comment to the question which quotes fragments of the lyrics, so no shortage of information there.

My opinion is that a question should be able to stand on its own to remain open. The content of the answers, the comments, and whether or not an answer is accepted should not really influence whether a question is closed or (re)opened.

- If a poor question has a good answer, then ideally the question should be edited and improved. For example, if important information is placed in the comments, then it should be edited into the body.
- If it is not possible to improve the question by editing, then closing the question is a good policy; deletion might be too harsh in such a case since we would be losing potentially good content given by the answerers.
- If the question is of such low quality that it demands deletion, then perhaps a new better question can be asked for which the good answers can find a home. The answerers can be pinged to move their answers to the new question. This way, good content is preserved and the quality of questions is also improved.

---

In this case, I submit that the question should be closed in the form that it currently stands. Consider that the entire body of the question is:

> This is the video link. It starts at 4:32.

With the video link dead, this means that the body is practically empty! In my mind, there is no doubt that such a question needs to be closed.

Should we wish to preserve the question, one could edit the comments as well as the title into the body of the question. This leaves us with something like the following:

> I am looking for an old school hip-hop song. Some bits of the lyrics are "psychic/sidekick", "belly of the beast", "sucker romance". I found the song in the background to a personal video dated 1999, so the song is probably from around the same period.

It is questionable whether this is sufficient; no effort is shown by the OP in identifying the song, for instance. But, at least it is an improvement. We currently have many questions that are open with only this level of detail, so I would not dispute it if a question with the above content stayed open.

Comment: I would still say: there was an accepted answer with a  lot of detail. It seems wrong to lose a good answer just because of the quality of the question.

Comment: @Angst The quality of *what* question? There *is* no question. The answer maybe was good once, when there actually was a question. But all the votes in the world can't make an answer to a question *noone ever asked* relevant in any reasonable way. Without a question it is a statement shouted into the empty void of nothingness and lost therein forevermore, but not an answer.

Comment: @Angst Unless the question is deleted, the closure still preserves the answers though. It only prevents more answers, but the existing answers are still there, so I'm not sure what do you mean by "losing a good answer". On the other hand, a good answer doesn't automatically make a bad question on-topic/acceptable on SE.

Comment: @AndrewT, I agree, a bad question should not be untouchable (for close/delete) just because of a good answer, but prob best decided case by case.

Answer (score 2):

Without the video, we have no question, really.  And, as it is, "Identify This..." questions are generally only useful to a small group of people.  Even though it has an answer, the answer now has no context.  It's probably something that should be deleted.